# c# как модифицировать маску в maskedtextbox для ввода года в виде "20"__?

Tags: c#

Как настроить маску `maskedtextbox` для ввода года так, чтобы пользователь вводил только последние 2 цифры года, а первые "20" уже бы содержались в `maskedtextbox`

Приемлемо любое другое решение без использования `maskedtextbox`

Comment: Может вы предложите мне другое решение без использования maskedtextbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант `maskedTextBox1.Mask = "2\\000";`

Про маску можно посмотреть здесь https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.4.php

Comment: @user334126 Я скорректировал ответ - писал по памяти, сейчас проверил - это то, что Вы хотите